# subprocess.Popen(cl, ..., shell=True) does not work like a shell command forwarder

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

My goal is to make pico2wave speak in python.

My code

```
cl = 'pico2wave --lang=de-DE --wave=/tmp/test.wav "Test"'
print(cl)
tempFile = '/dev/null'
with open(tempFile, "w+") as f:
  process = subprocess.Popen(cl, stdout=f, shell=True)
  cl = 'aplay /tmp/test.wav'
  print(cl)
  process = subprocess.Popen(cl, stdout=f, shell=True) 
  cl = 'rm -f /tmp/test.wav'
  print(cl)
  process = subprocess.Popen(cl, stdout=f, shell=True)
```

Using the print output in the command line it works. But with the python code it does not. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't wait for any of the processes to finish. To make it equivalent to running the shell commands one by one, you need to put a `process.wait()` call after each `Popen` so the command finishes before you launch the next process. In this case, `aplay` depends on `pico2wave` writing out `aplay`'s input, and depends on `rm` not removing it before it gets a chance to open it and read the contents.

Without the `process.wait()`, it's like running (note backgrounding `&`) this in the shell:

```
pico2wave --lang=de-DE --wave=/tmp/test.wav "Test" &
aplay /tmp/test.wav &
rm -f /tmp/test.wav &
```

which introduces all kinds of terrible race conditions.

Comment: @VitalisHommel: Yar. If you want to wait on the processes, and ensure they finished successfully, you might want to switch from using `Popen` to using `subprocess.check_call`, which waits for you, and raises an exception if the command has non-0 exit status (indicating failure). Nothing else would change in your original code, you'd just change `Popen` to `check_call` each time you see it.